# How to record the 301 Redirects URL?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, dom-events

I enter to browser this link 
https://google.com.vn;
Google redirect to https://www.google.com.vn;
I want alert full url redirect.
I used this code:

```
 processNewURL: function(aURI) {
       var tabIndex = gBrowser.tabContainer.selectedIndex;
       var referredFromURI = gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[tabIndex].linkedBrowser.webNavigation.referringURI.spec;
        alert(referredFromURI);
},
```

But it always alert https://www.google.com.vn,
and I tested with some short link example bit.ly/R9j52J . It isn't ok.
Please help me.

Comment: You have to remember that sometimes you are not redirected, so referringURI is null so referringURI.spec will throw an error. The other thing to remember is that the page being loaded is not always the selected tab, so your code above will throw false information (say for example: you started loading a tab, then its still loading and you focus another tab, then when that gBrowser load event fires it will give you information on the currently selected tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works, i also show 2 methods to get to webNavigation. the second method is just longed winded way to teach other stuff, recommended way is method 1.

```
var processNewURL = function(e) {
  console.log('e:', e);
       var win = e.originalTarget.defaultView;

     //start - method 1 to get to webNav:
     var webNav = win.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
.getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation);
     var referredFromURI = webNav.referringURI;
     //end - method 1

     //start - method 2 long winded way:
     /*
       var domWin = win.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                         .getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation)
                         .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
                         .rootTreeItem
                         .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                         .getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
       var tab = domWin.gBrowser._getTabForContentWindow(win);
       //console.log('tab:', tab);
       var referredFromURI = tab.linkedBrowser.webNavigation.referringURI;
       */
     //end - method 2

     if (referredFromURI != null) {
          win.alert('referred from:' + referredFromURI.spec);
     } else {
          win.alert('not redirected');
     }
}

gBrowser.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', processNewURL, false);
```

Comment: I tested this code but I need to get URL ENTER BROWSER. With this code when I enter http:// google.com.vn/. Code alert https:// www. google.com.vn/ . I need it alert http: //google.com.vn/ .

Comment: ah so the user types in `http` without the `s` and it redirects to `https` and you want it without the `s` huh?

Comment: Yes,  Noitidart, I want it without the S.